# Android IOException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android app who need to conect with a SQL Database. The app works fine, I do the connections with the server to a php file and with a asynk task and the class DefaultHttpClient (see below).

Then I read the recieved JSON file with a ReadJSONFeedTask`and process the data right. Everything works fine but when I connect two smartphones with the app to the SAME NETWORK, one of the app doesn't work.

If I turn off the wifi connection in the other smartphone and connect with 3G out of the network the two apps works again.

I'am tried debug and I think the second app make a IOException (see below), but I don't know how I could resolve it.

How I do to connect:

```
public class JSONActivity extends Activity {

public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 7000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 10000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    //HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));             
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file: " + URL);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Codigo != 200" + URL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ClientProtocolException " + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"IOException " + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

//esta no se usa de momento 
public class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    JSONArray jsonArray;

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I do pass the file like that:

```
ReadJSONFeedTask task = new ReadJSONFeedTask();
    task.execute('http://www.xxxx.es/archivo.php');
```

The debuger show the next error:

```
    09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /213.177.193.111:80 timed out
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-19 23:46:37.217: W/System.err(10202):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at com.gestion.LoginActivity.readJSONFeed(LoginActivity.java:3099)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at com.gestion.LoginActivity$CargarArchivo.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:307)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at com.gestion.LoginActivity$CargarArchivo.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-19 23:46:37.225: W/System.err(10202):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-19 23:46:37.233: W/System.err(10202):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-19 23:46:37.233: E/JSON(10202): IOException: Connect to /213.177.193.111:80 timed out
```

Thanks to give me a clue to solve this.
Regards

Comment: Make sure while both devices are connected to your WI-FI network that each get's a different IP from your DHCP server, or if it's set manually make sure to set different IPs..

Comment: Umm... yes I am sure the devides has differents IP, and this problem happend in any place where the two devices connect throught the same network...